# Merge PHP Array into One

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array whose schema is as follows:

```
            Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [text] => ans1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [text] => ans 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [text] => ans3
    )

)
```

And, I wish to merge it so the result is as follows:

```
Array (ans1,ans2,ans3);
```

I know that I can loop over it to get that result, but is there a faster and ready made function to do this?

One more thing, if I wish to produce a string like the following:

```
$str = 'ans1,ans2,ans3';
```

what can i do?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson array_merge wouldn't work on its own though cause the values all have the same key.

Comment: You need to loop through it and build the new array. When you have an array with just the texts, you can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to create that string.

Comment: @Loko I read the question wrong at first. That's why I removed the comment. :-)

Comment: You just need to create an array with the values of stdClass Object, and it is not "merge"

Comment: It seems to me that it's a multi-dimensional array and he wants to create a single-dimensional array out of it. After that he wishes to convert the array to a string.

Comment: The string you can get with `implode` [(manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php): `$str=implode( ',' , array )`. To get the values in a single array, you have to loop teh original array and extract them.

Comment: yes, @icecub, it is like what you explained

Comment: @icecub  Yes. you are right

Comment: There is no way of doing this without looping over it(I'm almost certain), since the values you want to merge are in the same array and it's a multidimensional array.

Comment: as per Esteban , we have a array_walk but isn't similar doing loop over array.

Comment: How do you get this array? I suspect you can make a small change upstream to get closer to the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done by using array_column() **in PHP7 or higher**:

```
// in your Case, the Column-Key is "text"
$array = array_column($array, 'column-key');
```

The Function extracts Values from a determined Column into a new Array.

And the other Issue is done by imploding the Result of array_column() with implode():

```
$array = implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: @rahulsingh I did some performance tests for you. `array_column() took 0.06 seconds on 10.000 runs` and `foreach() took 0.16 seconds on 10.000 runs`. So `array_column()` is definitely the best choice here.

Comment: You are almost there. Except it doesn't work in PHP 5 (`array_column()`).

Comment: @axiac `array_column()` seems to be working perfectly fine here on version 5.6.19?

Comment: @icecub Of course [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) works perfectly, even since PHP 5.5 when it was introduced, but it knows how to [handle objects](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#refsect1-function.array-column-changelog) only starting with PHP 7.0. Take a look here: https://3v4l.org/Unt6T

Comment: Thanks for the Info. I adjusted my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The schema of the OP represents an array of objects (see [here](https://3v4l.org/D4ZSo)), each bearing a text property.  With respect to the first question, I suggest using **array_map()**, as follows:

```
<?php

// create array of objects
$arr = [];
$tx = ["ans1","ans2","ans3"];

for ($i = 0, $max = 3; $i < $max; $i++) {
   $arr[] = new stdClass;
   $arr[$i]->text = $tx[$i];
}


//***** First Answer *******
$nu = array_map( function($e)
                 {
                    return $e->text;

                 }, $arr);

//***** Second Answer *******
$str = join(",",$nu);

// ***** Output *********
print_r( $nu );
print_r( $str );
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/KBVcb#output)

**array_map()** does speedy, behind-the-scenes iteration as it applies an anonymous function, to each element of $arr.  It returns a new array where each element contains the value of the text property of each stdClass object. While another respondent has suggested using **[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)** which one may apply to a multidimensional array or an array of objects, unfortunately, it fails to handle an array of objects in PHP 5 (see [here](https://3v4l.org/6PChU#output)) unlike the capable **array_map()**.

In answer to the second question, one may use [join()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) to concatenate the $nu array values with a comma, as the example illustrates.

Comment: I've did the numbers and here are the results: `array_column() took 0.06 seconds on 10.000 runs` -> `array_map() took 0.21 seconds on 10.000 runs`. The question was for the best and fastest solution. Even a plain old `foreach()` was faster than this.

Comment: php version: 5.6.19 `<?php $before = microtime(); // your code $after = microtime(); echo "array_map() took ". ($after-$before) . " seconds on 10.000 runs";` With the small change of `for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){ $nu = array_map('callback',$arr); }` to make it loop 10.000 times

Comment: @slevy1 now its better! But before, there was no Explanation. It is imho important to add Explanations for less experienced Users.

Comment: Oh, I removed the `var_dump($nu);` part of course. Otherwise it would take a whole lot longer.